# instrumenting mobile application error in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, mobile, rational-test-workbench

when I am trying to upload hybrid android app from my mobile using *IBM* rational test work mobile client, In eclipse it shows below mentioned error.How to solve this issue.

Message :

`An internal error occurred during: "Instrumenting Mobile Application..."`.

Stack Trace :

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.buildchain.AndroidBuildChain.getBuildchainPluginIds()[Ljava/lang/String;
at com.ibm.rational.test.lt.models.behavior.moeb.utils.BuildChainManager.uploadFile(BuildChainManager.java:484)
at com.ibm.rational.test.lt.models.behavior.moeb.utils.BuildChainManager.access$1(BuildChainManager.java:338)
at com.ibm.rational.test.lt.models.behavior.moeb.utils.BuildChainManager$BuildJob.run(BuildChainManager.java:969)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you don't have a standard installation.
this exception is raised by jvm when something very unexpected happends
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html

could you please post more informations about your config (RTW version, jvm version, eclipse.ini file) ? 
it could help us to point what is happening

Thanks,

Jerome Bozier

Senior Software Engineer, RTW Mobile Android, IBM

Comment: I have used following versions: Mobile First Platform Test Workbench 8.7.0.v20150720_1454, Java version 7 windows 8, 64 bit , Eclipse.ini file -  startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m

Comment: use 8702 version if possible (or even better 871, will be live around Mid October 2015). also, add  your jvm in eclipse.ini (it is not specified there), like this : <-vm
D:\work\IBM\SDP8702\jdk\jre\bin\javaw.exe>. it is possible that the jvm in your windows path does not work well, so better use the one coming from RTW install. On a general way, this kind of error show that your install is not coherent,